# update material ui from 3.9.3 to to the latest

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I tried to update material ui following the instructions on their [web site](https://material-ui.com/guides/migration-v3/)
from 3.9.3 to the latest version.

I ran `npm install @material-ui/core` and `npm install react@latest`
but I am getting the following error when I deploy my app:

```
hoist-non-react-statics.cjs.js:70 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
    at getPrototypeOf (<anonymous>)
    at e (hoist-non-react-statics.cjs.js:70)
    at n (withTheme.js:47)
    at Module.1038 (AppSettings.js:95)
    at u (index.html:1)
    at Object.620 (main.5ef97776.chunk.js:1)
    at u (index.html:1)
    at r (index.html:1)
    at Array.t [as push] (index.html:1)
    at main.5ef97776.chunk.js:1
```

These are the dependencies in my app:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@date-io/core": "^1.3.8",
    "@date-io/moment": "^1.3.11",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.4",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^3.0.2",
    "material-design-icons": "^3.0.1",
    "material-ui-pickers": "^2.2.4",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "react-app-polyfill": "^1.0.4",
    "react-dates": "^16.7.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "^3.3.0",
    "react-select": "^3.0.8",
    "core-js": "^2.6.12",
    "flux": "^3.1.3",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
  },
```

Any help with this?

Comment: You sure you have fixed all breaking changes? That is a major version change.

Comment: No, not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your package.json to use the latest version of Material-UI.

"dependencies": {
"@material-ui/core": "^4.0.0"
}

Replace version with the latest or desired version.

Run

npm install @material-ui/core

or

yarn add @material-ui/core

Comment: My package is already updated `"@material-ui/core": "^4.11.4"` with the latest version, but I am getting the error above when I deploy my app

Answer (score 0):

Follow this [guide](https://material-ui.com/guides/migration-v3/) on the changes you have to make. Remember in open-source environments, upgrading a package from `x.0.0` to `y.0.0` is considered a major version upgrade and will contain breaking changes 99% of the time. Simply bump the version and do nothing will almost guarantee to break your code.

Comment: what do you think I have been following? Did you read my post above? It is the same guide I posted.